# Drawing a ReUsable Image in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to draw an image like this in Android

[image: Circle Line]

I tried to design the image using a design tool and use it as a Drawable, but it gets pixelated in android. 
I use `UIBezierPath` to draw it in `iOS app`. Is it possible to achieve same thing on Android? 
This is what I achieved using `XML <layer-list> drawable tag`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:height="30dp" android:gravity="top">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="30dp" android:bottom="30dp" android:height="100dp" android:width="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:height="30dp" android:gravity="bottom">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image: Using Drawable]

And tried using `Paint and Canvas`

```
public class CircleLineImage extends View{

//Setup initial color
private int paintColor = Color.BLACK;
//Defines paint and canvas
private Paint drawPaint;

public CircleLineImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setupPaint();
}

private void setupPaint() {
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 10, drawPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(5, 10, 12, 200, drawPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(0, 220, 20, drawPaint);
}
}
```

[image: Using Canvas]

Thanks.

Comment: so the closest class in android would be `android.graphics.Path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a pen and paper and try sketching what you are trying to do when drawing to a canvas. **Pen and paper is still the best option to grasp what you want to do.**

### Content

You have 2 Ovals and a line inbetween. They are all aligned on the same x-Axis value. *There should be no change in the x values in your `draw*` calls.*

### Paint

```
drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Will not fill. To fill the circles you will need to set `FILL` on the paint object.

### Cut off circles

Your circles get cut off because you are trying outside the canvas. Again, just sketch things out, your view and canvas have a width and height, use them! Don't just assume arbitrary values for your bounds.

### So...

Go and calculate the center of your canvas (e.g. `canvas.width() / 2`). The same would go for the y values to evenly distribute and not hard code them.

A somewhat better solution would look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, 30, 20, drawPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, 170, 20, drawPaint);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawLine(centerX, 50, centerX, 150, drawPaint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out after going through the documentation. Thanks very much

Comment: What if I want to get the `canvas.x` or `canvas.y`?

Comment: @user3994005 the canvas is an arbitrary object to draw on, it has no coordinates itself, so you might want to use your views dimensions for getting information about its position. although I do not see what you need these for, since your target drawing just depends on width and height of the view

Answer (score 0):

Different screen denisities require different size images. If the drawable is just an png or jpg and you have only one image in drawable-hdpi folder then when you use the app with device that's density is xxhdpi (Nexus 5) for example, then the image is scaled up. Try to make different size drawables and add them to different android resource folders.

- drawable-mdpi (this will be the baseline, set this size as dp for ImageView)
- drawable-hdpi (1.5 x baseline)
- drawable-xhdpi (2 x baseline)
- drawable-xxhdpi (3 x baseline)
- drawable-xxxhdpi (4 x baseline)

See more in android tutorials: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html